disable payment method in PayPal
I use PayPal for payments. Lots of customers is trying to pay via Przelewy24 (Poland) method but it somehow doesn't work. I'd like to disable this option but to be honest I don't know how.
This is the code I have under the Payment button.
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=ARmXlvd2E6p0I2OrAtHySr4njP73BVndummym9I2uzdDrvmIgjFHne_kLcXZua4QmQwzEXVHMn7&components=buttons&currency=EUR"></script>

Where do I set up payment options? I can find the list of payment methods and description of Przelewy24 but I suppose I'm too dumb to understand it :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/przelewy24/
Can anyone simply explain if there is any checkbox for enabling/disabling payment methods?
Regards
Pawel

Use the disable-funding script parameter.
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=...&currency=EUR&disable-funding=p24"></script>

